# Return values from dialog box

Tags: c#

how to  send and return values in modal dialog form

Comment: Need more information.  What framework are you using?

Comment: Some clarification would be nice, yes. In my answer below I assumed you're looking for a type of input box similar to the MessageBox class, but that accepts a string input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this. It's designed to be a counterpart to MessageBox. It doesn't change its styling based on OS, though. It looks like Vista's.

Here's an example of it in action, from it's original home (a Paint.NET plugin).
It will expand to fit the prompt.

[image]

InputBox.cs:

```
    internal partial class InputBoxForm : Form
    {
        Size lbltextoriginalsize;
        Size pnlwhiteoroginalsize;
        public InputBoxForm(string text, string defaultvalue, string caption)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.pnlWhite.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.pnlWhite_Resize);
            this.lblText.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.lblText_Resize);
            picIcon.Image = SystemIcons.Question.ToBitmap();
            lbltextoriginalsize = lblText.Size;
            pnlwhiteoroginalsize = pnlWhite.Size;
            this.lblText.Text = text;
            this.txtOut.Text = defaultvalue;
            this.Text = caption;
        }

        private void lblText_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pnlWhite.Size += lblText.Size - lbltextoriginalsize;
        }

        private void pnlWhite_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Size += pnlWhite.Size - pnlwhiteoroginalsize;
        }

        public string Value
        {
            get { return txtOut.Text; }
        }
    }

    /// 
    /// A counterpart to the MessageBox class, designed to look similar (at least on Vista)
    /// 
    public static class InputBox
    {
        public static DialogResult Show(string text, out string result)
        {
            return ShowCore(null, text, null, null, out result);
        }
        public static DialogResult Show(IWin32Window owner, string text, out string result)
        {
            return ShowCore(owner, text, null, null, out result);
        }
        public static DialogResult Show(string text, string defaultValue, out string result)
        {
            return ShowCore(null, text, defaultValue, null, out result);
        }
        public static DialogResult Show(IWin32Window owner, string text, string defaultValue, out string result)
        {
            return ShowCore(owner, text, defaultValue, null, out result);
        }
        public static DialogResult Show(string text, string defaultValue, string caption, out string result)
        {
            return ShowCore(null, text, defaultValue, caption, out result);
        }
        public static DialogResult Show(IWin32Window owner, string text, string defaultValue, string caption, out string result)
        {
            return ShowCore(owner, text, defaultValue, caption, out result);
        }

        private static DialogResult ShowCore(IWin32Window owner, string text, string defaultValue, string caption, out string result)
        {
            InputBoxForm box = new InputBoxForm(text, defaultValue, caption);
            DialogResult retval = box.ShowDialog(owner);
            result = box.Value;
            return retval;
        }
    }
```

InputBox.Designer.cs:

```
    partial class InputBoxForm
    {
        /// 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// 
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// 
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// 
        /// true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// 
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// 
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.pnlWhite = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.lblText = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.picIcon = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.txtOut = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.btnOK = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btnCancel = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.pnlWhite.SuspendLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.picIcon)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // pnlWhite
            // 
            this.pnlWhite.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
                        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
                        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.pnlWhite.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.pnlWhite.Controls.Add(this.lblText);
            this.pnlWhite.Controls.Add(this.picIcon);
            this.pnlWhite.Controls.Add(this.txtOut);
            this.pnlWhite.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.pnlWhite.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
            this.pnlWhite.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(235, 84);
            this.pnlWhite.Name = "pnlWhite";
            this.pnlWhite.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(235, 84);
            this.pnlWhite.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // lblText
            // 
            this.lblText.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
                        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)));
            this.lblText.AutoSize = true;
            this.lblText.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(64, 26);
            this.lblText.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3, 0, 30, 30);
            this.lblText.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(159, 0);
            this.lblText.Name = "lblText";
            this.lblText.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(159, 13);
            this.lblText.TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // picIcon
            // 
            this.picIcon.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.picIcon.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(25, 26);
            this.picIcon.Name = "picIcon";
            this.picIcon.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(32, 32);
            this.picIcon.TabIndex = 1;
            this.picIcon.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // txtOut
            // 
            this.txtOut.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
                        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.txtOut.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(67, 50);
            this.txtOut.Name = "txtOut";
            this.txtOut.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(159, 20);
            this.txtOut.TabIndex = 5;
            // 
            // btnOK
            // 
            this.btnOK.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.btnOK.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
            this.btnOK.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(42, 96);
            this.btnOK.Name = "btnOK";
            this.btnOK.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(88, 26);
            this.btnOK.TabIndex = 3;
            this.btnOK.Text = "OK";
            this.btnOK.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // btnCancel
            // 
            this.btnCancel.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.btnCancel.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
            this.btnCancel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(138, 96);
            this.btnCancel.Name = "btnCancel";
            this.btnCancel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(88, 26);
            this.btnCancel.TabIndex = 4;
            this.btnCancel.Text = "Cancel";
            this.btnCancel.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // InputBoxForm
            // 
            this.AcceptButton = this.btnOK;
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.CancelButton = this.btnCancel;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(235, 133);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnCancel);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnOK);
            this.Controls.Add(this.pnlWhite);
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            this.MaximizeBox = false;
            this.MinimizeBox = false;
            this.Name = "InputBoxForm";
            this.ShowIcon = false;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            this.pnlWhite.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.pnlWhite.PerformLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.picIcon)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel pnlWhite;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox picIcon;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblText;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnOK;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnCancel;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtOut;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I usually do something like this:

```
public class MyInputDialog : Form {
   public static string Execute(string Prompt) {
      using (var f = new MyInputDialog() ) {
         f.lblPrompt.Text = Prompt;
         f.ShowModal();
         return f.txtInput.Text;
      }
   }
}
```

Leaving out all the error handling, what if the user cancels, etc.

Comment: I always was defining properties on the modal dialog and then read them back from the main form. Your solution looks more cleaner (for only one return parameter), however it does not return the return value of ShowModel. So, you don't know whether the user just clicked on the X, or really did change something.

Comment: That's true. I will sometimes return null for cancel if it seems appropriate, or else pass in a default value to Execute, and pass it back if cancelled.

Comment: For more than one return parameter, you could define a class/struct encapsulating them all, and return an instance of it.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would call the dialog box

```
 var regStoreForm = new RegisterStoreForm(storeID,password);
            if (regStoreForm.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                storeID = regStoreForm.StoreId;
                password = regStoreForm.StorePassword;
            };
            regStoreForm.Dispose();
```

And this is what the Dialog box looks like

```
 public partial class RegisterStoreForm : Form
    {
        public int StoreId { get; set; }
        public String StorePassword { get; set; }

        public RegisterStoreForm(int storeId,string password)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            StoreId = storeId;
            StorePassword = password;
            this.textBoxPassword.Text = StorePassword;
            this.textBoxStoreId.Text = StoreId.ToString();
        }

        private void OKbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StoreId = Convert.ToInt16(textBoxStoreId.Text);
            StorePassword = textBoxPassword.Text;
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you `Interaction.InputBox` (`Microsoft.VisualBasic` reference needed):

```
inputValue = Interaction.InputBox("Text for the prompt", "Title of the dialog", "");
```

When user presses Cancel, `inputValue` will be `""`.