# My dialog return value doesn't work

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I have a custom form that's returning the values to the main form but it's not seeing the variables. I don't think I'm making this very clear so I'll include the links to the examples of what I'm trying to do.

- [[Return values from dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818785/return-values-from-dialog-box)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818785/return-values-from-dialog-box)
- [too long to display](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/DipalChoksi/PassingDataBetweenaWindowsFormandDialogBoxes11242005035025AM)

I know I'm probably overlooking something very easy and or obvious but here is what I have.

form1.cs:

```
private void addTime_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form add = new addTime(false, new string[] { "", "" });
    if (add.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // the line not working
        Label1.Text = add.Details;
        // reports with:'System.Windows.Forms.Form' does not contain a
        // definition for 'Details' and no extension method 'Details' accepting       
        // a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' could be found (are you
        // missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
    }
}
```

addTime.cs:

```
internal class addTime : Form
{
    //..

    private string _details;
    public string Details
    {
        get { return _details; }
        private set { _details = value; }
    }

    private string _goalTime;
    public string GoalTime
    {
        get { return _goalTime; }
        private set { _goalTime = value; }
    }

    private void applybtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Details = detailslbl.Text;
        GoalTime = goalTimelbl.Text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your 'add' variable is of type Form, not addTime and the Form type does not have a Details property.

Try this line instead:

```
addTime add = new addTime(false, new string[] { "", "" });
```

Comment: WOW! I knew it had to be something simple! Lol, thanks though I feel like an idiot now.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the DialogResult property of the child form

```
DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
```

in the button click .

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the form's dialogResult property to OK. You haven't specified it in your code.

After the correct criteria have been met you would set it like this.

```
If (//condition)
{
this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
This.Close();
}
```