# C# Forms How to get value from Prompt Dialog

Tags: c#, winforms, class, dialog, prompt

I have a class called "AddChips" it's basically Prompt Dialog with some buttons and a `TextBox` the user enter's some data in it and i want to get the data that he just entered and send it back to some other class let's say "Form1" and give the data to integer called Chips

```
public static string ShowDialog(string text, string caption)
{
    Form prompt = new Form();
    prompt.Width = 500;
    prompt.Height = 150;
    prompt.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
    prompt.Text = caption;
    prompt.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    Label textLabel = new Label() { Left = 50, Top = 20, Text = text };
    TextBox textBox = new TextBox() { Left = 50, Top = 50, Width = 400 };
    Button confirmation = new Button() { Text = "Ok", Left = 350, Width = 100, Top = 70, DialogResult = DialogResult.OK };
    Button leaveApp = new Button() { Text = "No", Left = 250, Width = 100, Top = 70, DialogResult = DialogResult.OK };
    confirmation.Click += (sender, e) => { new Form1() { Chips = int.Parse(textBox.Text) }; };
    leaveApp.Click += (sender, e) => { Application.Exit(); };
    prompt.Controls.Add(textBox);
    prompt.Controls.Add(confirmation);
    prompt.Controls.Add(leaveApp);
    prompt.Controls.Add(textLabel);
    textLabel.Width = 300;
    prompt.AcceptButton = confirmation;
    return prompt.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK ? textBox.Text : "";
}
```

Comment: You can't send it back to Form1 if you create a new Form1.  You would probably be better off using the designer for your dialogs.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this can post some sample code as an answer with textbox and 2 buttons ?

Comment: I dont know how to do that

Comment: this is very simple @denis but your only response to comments is `I don't know how to do that` do you know how to do a `Google Search` and search on `DialogResult.Ok` what you want is an if statement
`if (prompt.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK){ }` then you capture the values that were populated in the other form. you need to create an instance of the other form and in your calling form keep local variables of what you are wanting.. then when the created instance of the form returns you can still get at the obkect as long as you did not destroy it.. do some `Googling`

Comment: here is something to try if you don't understand this then I don't know what to do because it's pretty straight forward [Return Values from A Dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818785/return-values-from-dialog-box)

Comment: As @MethodMan just explained, you'll also need to create a property on this new form that is public and that is updated when you click OK. After that just read it using an instance of you form. This is really very easy to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used on prompt form Like this:

```
public string ValueIWant { get; set; }

private void btnSetValueIWant_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbxValue.Text))
    {
        ValueIWant= txtbxValue.Text;
        this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
        Close();
    }
}
```

and on the other form i get Value:

```
frmValue f= new frmValue ();
            if (f.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
               string ValueIWantFromProptForm=f.ValueIWant ;
            }
```

It Works for me.